# How to bind the selected item from a select list to if condition in razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I'm implementing a project with asp.net core. I have an Edit view which its code is like below:

```
 @model CSDDashboard.Models.ApplicantViewModel
 <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">      </script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  @*  $(".person").show(); *@
    @* $(".legal").hide();  *@
    $('#applicantvm_ApplicantType').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $(".person").show();
            if ($(".legal").show()) {
                $(".legal").hide();
            }
        } else { 
            $(".legal").show();
            if ($(".person").show()) {
                $(".person").hide();
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>


   @{
ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
 }

 <h1>Edit</h1>

 <h4>applicant</h4>
 <hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="applicantvm.ApplicantId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="applicantvm.ApplicantType" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="applicantvm.ApplicantType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ApplicantType"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="applicantvm.ApplicantType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="applicantvm.Address" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="applicantvm.Address" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="applicantvm.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="applicantvm.Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="applicantvm.Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="applicantvm.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="applicantvm.Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="applicantvm.Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="applicantvm.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @if (Model.applicantvm.ApplicantType == 2)
        {
            <div class="form-group legal">
                <label asp-for="legalapplicantvm.EconomicCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="legalapplicantvm.EconomicCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="legalapplicantvm.EconomicCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group legal">
                <label asp-for="legalapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="legalapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="legalapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group legal">
                <label asp-for="legalapplicantvm.RegisterNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="legalapplicantvm.RegisterNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="legalapplicantvm.RegisterNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        }
   else
    {
        <div class="form-group person">
            <label asp-for="personapplicantvm.Username" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="personapplicantvm.Username" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="personapplicantvm.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group person">
            <label asp-for="personapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="personapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="personapplicantvm.NationalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group person">
            <label asp-for="personapplicantvm.IssuePlace" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="personapplicantvm.IssuePlace" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="personapplicantvm.IssuePlace" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group person">
            <label asp-for="personapplicantvm.BirthCertificateNo" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="personapplicantvm.BirthCertificateNo" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="personapplicantvm.BirthCertificateNo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
  </div>

  <div>
  <a asp-action="Index">Back to list</a>
  </div>

  @section Scripts {
  @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
  }
```

if Model.applicantvm.ApplicantType == 2 then the related fields are shown to the user, otherwise, some other fields in the else section have to be shown to the user. Now my problem is, I don't know how to bind the selected value from selectlist to the if condition in my code. In my code, for instance if the original page just show the legal class fields then when I change the selectlist item to the other value, then person class fields aren't shown to the user. I appreciate if anyone solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not the expert here neither, but what if you wrap those related fields in  with Id 
like

```
 <div id="personalApplication">
     //related fields
 </div>
 <div id="legalApplication">
     //related fields
 </div>
```

and lose the @if(Model.applicantvm.ApplicantType == 2) and else part around the related fields.
and since you have a select list you could get values on selected options like.
then on page read, you can add

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if($('#applicantvm_ApplicantType option:selected').val() != 1){
         $("#personalApplication").show();
         $("#legalApplication").hide();
      }
     else{
         $("#personalApplication").hide();
          $("#legalApplication").show();
      }
     $("#applicantvm_ApplicantType").on("change", function () {
         if ($('#applicantvm_ApplicantType option:selected').val() != 1) {
            $("#personalApplication").show();
            $("#legalApplication").hide();


         } else {
            $("#personalApplication").hide();
            $("#legalApplication").show();

         }
     })

 });
 </script>
```